# Finding the general solution of a second order PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I want to find the general solution of

> $$\frac{\partial^2f(x,y)}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2f(x,y)}{\partial y^2}+A^2f(x,y)=0,$$
>   with $f$ a real valued function and $A$ a real constant.

I know that $f(x,y)=\sin(\frac{m}{\sqrt{2}}(x+y))$ is a solution of this, but how do I find a *general* solution?

Comment: Let $f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$ for some $g,h$ and subsititute.

Comment: @hamidkamali how do I know that thats allowed?

Comment: It is a well-known method to solving the PDE's from second order by constant coefficient.

Answer (score 1):

$$f_{xx}+f_{yy}+A^2f(x,y)=0$$
The search for particular solutions with the separation of variables method $f=F(x)G(y)$ leads to :
$$\frac{F''}{F}+\frac{G''}{G}=-A^2 \quad\implies\quad
\begin{cases}
\frac{F''}{F}=\alpha-\frac{1}{2}A^2 \quad\to\quad F=e^{\sqrt{\alpha-\frac{1}{2}A^2}\:x}\\
\frac{G''}{G}=-\alpha-\frac{1}{2}A^2 \quad\to\quad G=e^{\sqrt{-\alpha-\frac{1}{2}A^2}\:y} \\
\end{cases}
$$
where $\alpha$ is any real or complex number.
$$f_{\alpha}=c_{\alpha}e^{\sqrt{\alpha-\frac{1}{2}A^2}\:x+ \sqrt{-\alpha-\frac{1}{2}A^2}\:y}$$
where $c_{\alpha}$ is any real or complex number.
$$u(x,y)=\sum_{\text{any } \alpha}c_{\alpha}e^{\sqrt{\alpha-\frac{1}{2}A^2}\:x+ \sqrt{-\alpha-\frac{1}{2}A^2}\:y} $$
This discret form can be extended to continuous :
$$u(x,y)=\int c(s)e^{\sqrt{\alpha(s)-\frac{1}{2}A^2}\:x+ \sqrt{-\alpha(s)-\frac{1}{2}A^2}\:y} ds$$
where $\alpha(s)$ and $c(s)$ are any real or complex functions, insofar possible integration.